# What Java memory profiler applications will work on Windows 7 64-bit with Java 1.4 32-bit?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I'm trying to find a memory leak in an old Java 1.4 application. I have tried to use jmp but unfortunately I've had no luck getting it working (is it actually supported in Windows 7?).

If anyone knows of any free/open source Java 1.4 memory profilers that definitely work on Windows 7 64-bit, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Add the `-XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Temp\HeapDump` argument when starting the app
2. Wait until it crashes with OutOfMemory exception
3. Use [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to see what was using so much memory.

Answer (score 1):

I used JMP until we moved to Java 1.6.

http://www.khelekore.org/jmp/

GCViewer is nice if you're just verifying leaks:

http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html

Answer (score 0):

SAP has contributed a memory analyzer to eclipse which gives very nice and elaborate reports. check the below link

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try

```
jps -l
jmap -histo <pid>
```

And then, I would install Java 6, run the same application, and use:

```
jconsole
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used YourKit Java profiler http://www.yourkit.com .

Answer (score -1):

You're running on a 1.4 JVM, correct? It's not a 1.4-compiled class running on a 1.6 JVM? And is there a reason that you can't run the application on a 1.6 JVM, at least in a development environment?

If not, the built-in HProf agent should work, at least to find a memory leak. It will tell you what objects are [live](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) when you kill your program, and where they were allocated.

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe that you need to use the `-Xrunhprof` invocation option (the linked doc invokes with `-agentlib`, which I think may have been added in 1.5). Also, I think there was a version of 1.4 that supported the "modern" debug interface, so could be used with JConsole.

Comment: It's 1.4 JDK running on 1.5 JRE.

Comment: @nbolton - that makes no sense. Do you mean that you *compiled* using a 1.4 JDK and are *running* on a 1.5 JRE? In that case, you can use whatever profiler you like, as long as it works with a 1.5 JRE (and to the best of my knowledge, that includes everything out there). If you are having problems connecting to a 1.5 JRE, start examining your system components and your assumptions; one of them is not what you think it is.

Comment: @nbolton - sorry, my crystal ball is out for repair. I hope the downvote felt good for you too.